# Is there a way to configure the "Super W" effect?

Tags: unity

I'd like to configure the "Super W" effect, is it possible? I can't find it in the ccsm. Using Unity 3D in Ubuntu 11.10. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A number ofaspects of the 'Super-W' effect may be configured from CCSM.  The options are found under the **Scale** addon in the **Window Management** section of CCSM.